# Angular on Node JS web service - GET http://127.0.0.1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am developing website using AngularJS and host it within NodeJS (Express JS) web service. The AngularJS uses the data on some endpoints served by NodeJS. In another word, the NodeJS has endpoints which serve AngularJS web page and providing data needed.

Before host the webpage on my virtual machine (web service), I use my host machine to host it. The webpage then tried to request the data to my virtual machine's endpoint and it works fine.

However, when I'm hosting it on my virtual machine (web service) and changed to request data on my localhost (http://127.0.0.1:3000/data), I am now getting `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/data net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

**What I have tried**

First, I thought it was occurred because of cross origin resource sharing, so I am enabling that in my NodeJS by adding these lines of code (taken from [this site](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

However, it still does not help at all. I am still getting the same error message.

Later, I thought it probably my firewall was blocking the access. I then turned off my firewall and it still failed to fix my problem.

I believe it happened because of my webpage trying to access endpoint on its localhost API, which should be overcome with CORS handling on my first attempt.

What is causing this exactly if it is not CORS? How do I overcome this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update: Node JS Route Code**

```
var express = require('express');
var app =express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/admin/login/:user/:pass', function(appReq,appRes){
    appRes.status(200).send('1');
    appRes.end();
});

app.get('/*', function(appReq, appRes){
    fs.readFile('./public/index.html', function(err,data){
        if (err) {
            appRes.writeHead(500);
            appRes.end('Error loading html');
        }
        else {
            appRes.writeHead(200);
            appRes.end(data);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('express app listening at http://'+hostname+":"+port+'/');
});
```

Here is my AngularJS [GitHub repo](https://github.com/darrencl/salesappadmin)

Comment: Can you please share the code over GitHub or similar, where we can look at it. The above mentioned code is not sufficiant to analyse what you are trying to serve and how you are trying to serve it.

Comment: @Jeet Sure, I will upload my angular to github and will update my node js routing code here as my node js file is huge.

Comment: if you want to confirm that the issue occur due to core install this extension  in your browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en so this will allow cors and 2nd thing if you want to server your angular project in express you need to first make it build like "ng build --production" .you  will get "dist" folder.place that folder in express public file or serve these file as static resources.
if you share your server file it will help me to show you exact solution.

Comment: // serve angular front end files from root path
app.use('/', express.static('dist', { redirect: false }));

// rewrite virtual urls to angular app to enable refreshing of internal pages
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));
});
app.listen(3000,function(req,res)

Comment: oh my God just mention the port in url

Comment: 127.0.0.1:3000/data or what ever your port

Comment: @Adiii I have mentioned the port in my URL and still not working, I did not write the port above for simplicity, I will update it. I am using public folder and set it as static. What is the function of ng build? Will it help in this case?

Comment: yeah definatly ng build --production is for production purpose and make dist folder so you only need to hit index file and index will handle all route for you pls share your express code

Comment: @Jeet I have updated my question and adding my github repo for my angular code

Comment: @Adiii Here is my NodeJS code: https://github.com/darrencl/salesappserverscript/blob/master/app.js

Comment: @Adiii Please let me know what I did wrong if you found one. The endpoint for serving the webpage is at the bottom-most `'/*'` endpoint

Comment: It’s not related to CORS. Servers don’t block requests based on CORS configuration settings. Instead they respond to requests in exactly the same way they would otherwise—except they either include Access-Control-\* headers in the response, or they don’t. It’s up to the browser to decide, based on the response headers that come back, whether or not to expose the response to your frontend JavaScript code. So server CORS configuration settings are never going cause you to see an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Comment: @sideshowbarker so what do you think is causing this issue? Can you help me with possible solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have insight into what the cause might be—I just wanted to help you rule out the CORS configuration as a cause.

Comment: let me check it bro in next thirty mint and please also share your dist folder in github after ng build you will get dist folder in angular project which will be of 2-4 mb

Comment: looking for dist folder pls do it share it on github bro

Comment: @Adiii Sorry I have never done that before, need your guidance. I have installed angcli in my project, in what path should I do `ng build --prod`?

Comment: @Adiii Hi man, no worries I have solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out using localhost IP is wrong. It is probably due to the JavaScript is sent to the client and the browser then interprets localhost is the client's localhost. Therefore, changing the localhost to my actual IP address solved my problem.

Comment: Good that's why I told u look in to ip